# Correct use of templates for specific type-based optimization in C++ library

Tags: c++, templates

If I have a function that I want to implement for all types but then have specific optimizations for some types, how do I do this correctly in C++ with templates?

At the moment, in the header file I have:

```
template <class T> void Function(const T &src)
{
   printf("something generic to fall back on with src if nothing else fits");
}

void Function(const int &src);
void Function(const float &src);
void Function(const double &src);
```

Then in the cpp file I have:

```
void Function(const int &src) { printf("specialization %d\n", src); }
void Function(const float &src) { printf("specialization %g\n", src); }
void Function(const double &src) { printf("specialization %g\n", src); }
```

Firstly I wanted to check that I am correct in not putting `template<>` in front of the declarations in the header file? I don't fully understand the use of `template` with empty brackets.

Now it turns out that I have actually lots of cases of optimized implementations for about 10 different types. Some of them are almost the same, like the versions for `float` and `double` above. Therefore it makes sense if I can template a subset of the specializations that are within the cpp file, but I don't see how to do that. Is the only way to call a separate internal templated function?

What I want is a catch all implementation that is generic and is present in the header file which can be include by the application that uses the library, then I want a set of identical templated specializations for a subset of known data types that are exported from the library and implemented in the cpp file, and then finally a set of highly optimized cases for just one or two types that are also in the cpp file.

How can I best achieve this?

Comment: You can write a template which will only be considered for (list of types). `std::enable_if` is your friend there.

Comment: Look at the examples here.  I think they do exactly what you are looking for (in terms of a common function for float and double), for example: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if

Comment: Very interesting, particularly the `enable_if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're 100% right that you don't need the `template<>` for this.  You only need `template` when writing a template function, and you aren't writing template function specializations, you're making entirely new functions, that happen to have the same name.

```
//template function - templated on any type
template <class T> void Function(const T &src); 
//template function specialization for std::vector, itself takes 2 template params
//(This technically only works with classes, not functions, for unrelated 
// reasons, but it would use this syntax)
template <class U, class A> void Function<std::vector<U,A>>(const std::vector<U,A>& src);
//template function specialization for int, itself takes 0 template params
template<> void Function<int>(const int& src)

//not in any way a template, this is a completely unrelated regular function
void Function(double);
```

If you have nearly similar functions with different types, that calls 100% for templates!  So use them!  Note that since this template is only used in a single cpp file, it doesn't need to be in a header.  The template itself can be in the cpp file.  So, in your .cpp file, write this:

```
 template<class flttype>
 void FloatFunction(const flttype&src) {
     printf("specialization %g\n", src);
 }

 void Function(const float &src) { FloatFunction(src);}
 void Function(const double &src) { FloatFunction(src);}
```

---

You mentioned that these other function with the same name should be template specializations.  That's not what you're doing, but that's also easy to do.  In fact, it's surprisingly like regular functions.  Change your prototypes to these:

```
template <class T> void Function(const T &src)
{
   printf("something generic to fall back on with src if nothing else fits");
}

template<> void Function<int>(const int &src);
template<> void Function<float>(const float &src);
template<> void Function<double>(const double &src);
```

and then change the code in your cpp files to these:

```
template<> void Function<int>(const int &src) { printf("specialization %d\n", src); }
template<> void Function<float>(const float &src) { printf("specialization %g\n", src); }
template<> void Function<double>(const double &src) { printf("specialization %g\n", src); }
```

Comment: What's the actual advantage / difference between using those template specializations you show above with <> versus doing it the way that is shown in my question?

Comment: @Robotbugs: Your question uses overloads, instead of specializations.  While there probably are pros and cons, the only thing I can think of is that with the overloads, the caller can use `Function<int>` to force it to use the "generic" version.  However, I don't know if that's a pro or con.

Comment: `template <class U, class A> void Function<std::vector<U,A>>(const std::vector&src);` won't compile - you can't partially specialize function templates. `template <class U, class A> void Function(const std::vector<U, A>& src);` does compile, but is a separate overload, not a specialization.

Comment: @T.C.: Ah right, I always forget that.  I've put in a note that this is the syntax that would be used if it weren't otherwise disallowed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need template specialization in your example: Overload resolution takes care of things for you.

Remember: When matches would otherwise be equal, non-template functions are preferred during overload resolution over template functions.

Therefore, for `int`s, the compiler will prefer the overload that explicitly takes an `int` (i.e. is not a template) to the one wherein it could deduce `T` to `int` and form a template match.

To try and clear up your confusion about `template <>`, you use it when you're declaring a specialized template, and you've specialized away all the template parameters.  You can specialize function templates, but in many (perhaps "most") cases this is unnecessary and overloading (as you've done) is quicker and easier.

In your case, however, your non-template functions are not templates at all, so you're not specializing anything, and therefore you don't declare them as templates (empty parameter list or otherwise).